# Expanding multiValueExtendedProperties on calendars not working

Tags: api, microsoft-graph-api

I have an issue, calling `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars?$expand=multiValueExtendedProperties` doesn't return the multiValueExtendedProperties response.

And if I try `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars/AAMkADQ0MTkyMDM1LTRhYWQtNGU5NC1iMTNiLWQwMGVkOTc3Njg0YgBGAAAAAADqewFH7jyUQLayRkU-YSm8BwCiRV4wB9ZcTLOUnr6Oobk4AAAAAAEGAACiRV4wB9ZcTLOUnr6Oobk4AAO9PFapAAA=?$expand=multiValueExtendedProperties` same thing, no multiValueExtendedProperties.

How to get this property ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the example as per the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/multivaluelegacyextendedproperty-get?view=graph-rest-1.0#http-request) to get a resource instance expanded with the extended property which matches a filter on the id property.

Request -

GET /me/calendars/{id}?$expand=multiValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq '{id_value}')

GET /users/{id|userPrincipalName}/calendars/{id}?$expand=multiValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq '{id_value}')

I tried the same and it worked for me [image]